# Find the first key by date field using sql and output also have other fields

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, vertica

I want to query the first occurrence of every name according to the earliest date. The output should have the complete row. Please help me to write the query in sql.

Input:

```
  Name |    ID |    payment_date |  Pack
 ------+-------+-----------------+-------
    A  |    11 |    31-Jan       |  P
    C  |    13 |    31-Jan       |  Q
    B  |    2  |    31-Jan       |  R
    C  |    3  |    28-Jan       |  P
    D  |    23 |    29-Jan       |  Q
    B  |    11 |    30-Jan       |  R
    A  |    17 |    25-Jan       |  P
    C  |    13 |    26-Jan       |  Q
    D  |    17 |    2-Feb        |  R
    B  |    23 |    3-Feb        |  P
    A  |    45 |    4-Feb        |  Q
    B  |    3  |    5-Feb        |  R
```

Output:

```
  Name |    ID | payment_date | Pack
  -----+-------+--------------+-----
    A  |    17 | 25-Jan       | P
    B  |    11 | 30-Jan       | R
    C  |    13 | 26-Jan       | Q
    D  |    23 | 29-Jan       | Q
```

Comment: So... is your `payment_date` a `date` data type or are you actually storing the `payment_date` in a character data type like that?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: yes the payment date is a date type and i am using vertica

Answer (score 0):

If your `payment_date` is a date data type, you can use `not exists()` like so:

```
select *
from t
where not exists (
  select 1
  from t i
  where i.Name = t.Name
    and i.payment_date < t.payment_date
    )
```

rextester demo (sql server): http://rextester.com/OKB46268

returns

```
+------+----+-------------+------+
| Name | Id | PaymentDate | Pack |
+------+----+-------------+------+
| A    | 17 | 2017-01-25  | P    |
| B    | 11 | 2017-01-30  | R    |
| C    | 13 | 2017-01-26  | Q    |
| D    | 23 | 2017-01-29  | Q    |
+------+----+-------------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks, here t stands for table name and i for?

Comment: @Nishantranjan `i` is an alias for table `t`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the min function, also assuming `payment_date` is a date type:

```
select Name, ID, min(payment_date), Pack from mytable
group by payment_date,Name, ID, Pack
order by Name
```

The downfall about this method is putting all of the fields in the group by.

Comment: It doesn't returns the desired output.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I wasn't sure on the DBMS when I answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Vertica's enhanced LIMIT clause:

```
WITH
-- input, don't use in real query
input(Name,ID,payment_date,Pack) AS (
          SELECT 'A',11,DATE '31-Jan-2017','P'
UNION ALL SELECT 'C',13,DATE '31-Jan-2017','Q'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B',2, DATE '31-Jan-2017','R'
UNION ALL SELECT 'C',3, DATE '28-Jan-2017','P'
UNION ALL SELECT 'D',23,DATE '29-Jan-2017','Q'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B',11,DATE '30-Jan-2017','R'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',17,DATE '25-Jan-2017','P'
UNION ALL SELECT 'C',13,DATE '26-Jan-2017','Q'
UNION ALL SELECT 'D',17,DATE  '2-Feb-2017','R'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B',23,DATE  '3-Feb-2017','P'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',45,DATE  '4-Feb-2017','Q'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B',3, DATE  '5-Feb-2017','R'
)
-- end of input , start real query here:
SELECT * FROM input
LIMIT 1 OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY payment_date)
;
```

Happy playing ...
Marco the Sane