# Get aggregate over n last values in vertica

Tags: sql, analytics, vertica

We have table that has the columns `dates`,`sales` and `item`.

An item's price can be different at every sale, and we want to find the price of an item, averaged over its *most recent* 50 sales.

Is there a way to do this using analytical functions in Vertica?

For a popular item, all these 50 sales could be from this week. For another, we may need to have a 3 month window.

Can we know what these windows are, per `item` ?

Comment: show some sample data and the expected result as well as your attempt.

Comment: Yes, selecting the relevant set of rows would fall under [tag:greatest-n-per-group] (where `n = 50`), so you can use [the standard answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group).  Given [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44209336/812837) there may be a simpler way to write the query, although I can't confirm that syntax is valid (not finding it listed in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a window-frame clause to get the value on every row:

```
select t.*,
       avg(t.price) over (partition by item
                          order by t.date desc
                          rows between 49 preceding and current row
                         ) as avg_price_50
from t;
```

On re-reading the question, I suspect you want a single row per item.  For that, use `row_number()`:

```
select t.item, avg(t.price)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item order by t.date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 50
group by item;
```